# Dynamic and persistent data

Tags: android

It is stated in documentation that `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` is called before placing the activity in such a background state, allowing you to save away any **dynamic** instance state in your activity into the given Bundle. Note that it is important to save **persistent** data in `onPause()` instead of `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.

What is the best way to distinguish dynamic data with persistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persistent data is data that must survive application restart, like user settings, etc..

Comment: Conversely, dynamic data would be transient contents of forms and such. To draw an analogy with a popular Windows desktop app, persistent data is the Word document and dynamic data is what the user is typing into the find-and-replace dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at this: Dynamic data is only stored in [RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8092164/869501). Persistent data can survive device power-off.