# Where is the bundle of onSaveInstanceState saved?

Tags: android

I would like to know where the bundle "outState" of the method [onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) is stored.

Is it stored in memory or in the device storage?

I am concerned about the security of the data which is stored in the bundle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's any way that any malicious background process can get at the bundle data of your application.  It is not documented how Android treats the Bundle data. It may or may not be written to disk in the event that your app is cleaned, while backgrounded.  However, given that we don't know whether or not this data is saved to disk, and if it is, given that we have no clue where, and almost certainly don't have read access to that part of the disk, I wouldn't worry about some third party process being able to recover that data.

Consequently I'm not clear what you might think the exposure is.  Though I may be missing something.
However, in answer to your question, it is absolutely in memory while your app is alive, and if your app is backgrounded it may or may not be written somewhere hidden, but we dont' know because Google hasn't told us.

It's destroyed along with the application when the memory is collected.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted to know

Comment: This is an inaccurate answer. Consider the case the app process is auto-killed by OS (while the app was in the background) and then user comes back to the app, then OS restores the app (creates a new process and restores the activity stack). Despite the app process was not present for some time, the bundle is supplied to a restored activity, so it was somehow/somewhere stored within the system. In its turn, the system just does not determine how exactly it stores bundles, so in theory it might use the filesystem.

Comment: You can also check the related answer from CommonsWare: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12468776/247013

Comment: @Arhimed, I think you're splitting hairs, but I'll edit my answer just to be clear.

Comment: @GeniaS. Thanks for your edit. Now it clearly states that we just don't know where the bundle is stored while the process is killed.

Comment: "It's destroyed along with the application when the memory is collected." - No, this last sentence is incorrect and contradictory to the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a detailed answer for where the `outState` Bundle data is saved:

> ...Bundles are an IPC mechanism, so it's not going to the filesystem. But now there's a P involved – which process is it? And what is that process doing with this data? And do I need to be worried about it? It turns out that these instance state bundles are **stored in the Activity Manager service**. This service is implemented under the package com.android.server.am in the Android source code. Recall that Activities are stacked one on top of another and that Android calls these stacks “Tasks”... Each of these tasks is represented internally with an object of class **TaskRecord**. This class contains an array of **ActivityRecord** objects, each of which manages the state of an Activity. ActivityRecord contains a member of type Bundle named icicle. This icicle-bundle is the saved instance state and **it is actually stored in the memory space of the Activity Manager service**.

*Source: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/android-onsaveinstancestate-bundle-secret-safe-daniel-pietsch/*

Answer (score 10):

**To store data only for application lifetime (ie temporarily), use the onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) activity event**

**This data will only be held in memory until the application is closed**, the data will be available any time that this activity starts within the current lifetime of the application.

**Explanation:** if data is stored here by activity A then the application shows a different activity or rotates the screen (hence closing A) and then returns to A the data can be retrieved to populate the controls. However if the application is closed and opened again the data will be gone and the controls will revert to their default values.

Example of use: storing text typed in by user and selections making up an order, blog entry, message, etc...

**Note:**

It’s important to notice that only the Activity is destroyed and recreated, not your whole application! An Android application can consist of many Activities, Services and ContentProviders! If the application is closed (for example by pressing the “Back” Button, then all values will be gone. savedInstaceState is only there to preserve data temporary when an Activity is destroyed/recreated, not the application itself.

If you want to preserve data permanently, you need to save it either as Preferences or in a ContentProvider/database.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know that the data is held in memory.

Answer (score 8):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#use_onsaveinstancestate_as_backup_to_handle_system-initiated_process_death) has been updated and indicates precisely that the state is serialized to disk:

> Saved instance state bundles persist both configuration changes and process death, but are limited by amount of storage and speed because `onSavedInstanceState()` **serializes data to disk.**

You can also found a table comparing the differents approches to preserving UI state

[image: Option for preserving UI state]

Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Comment: It's interesting that as for February 2024 the same doc says that SavedInstanceState is kept in memory just like ViewModel, but it also says that it's serialized/deserialized

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be in memory, but the best way to protect your data would be not to trust the system and encrypt it.  Never trust the client (in this case the client being the OS).

**EDIT:**

To be clear, I'm not saying encrypt the bundle. Rather I'm saying that any sensitive data should not be put into the bundle. If you **must** put custom data in the bundle, then encrypt it.

But ultimately you should keep as little sensitive data on the client as possible.  This is the same reason a e-commerce site would only show the last 4 digits of a credit card.

Comment: Android uses `onSaveInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState` to persist the UI state of each view when the system kills an activity that may need to be restored in the future (e.g., on screen rotation or low memory). If you really wanted to encrypt that information (you don't), you would need to save and restore all of the state information for all of the views yourself. I can think of no application where the name of the text field that has the focus is something that you'd need to encrypt...

Comment: I'm not saying encrypt the bundle. Rather I'm saying that any sensitive data should not be put into the bundle. If you must put custom data in the bundle, then encrypt it.